# Prepare dataset for further processing in R by unnesting cell array

Tags: r, matlab, data-structures, cell-array

I have used Matlab to read in the data of a large number of Excel files with experiment data and store them in a (nested) cell array. My plan was to use the cell array for further analysis in R.

As I misunderstood the use of a cell array, I created a 4-level nested cell array where on **each level** the first row contains character vectors for each column (e.g. `Var1` `Var2` etc.) the rows below that contain a cell which leads to the next level of data (until the lowest level where the actual data is stored).

I noticed that a cell array was rather unsuitable for my plan as R seems to have problems with nested cell arrays. Also, I cannot use `cell2mat` as the first row of each level of cell array is not a double data type.

Therefore I was wondering if there are any experiences for transferring Matlab data to R for nested data sets (which type of variable to use etc.) and if there are ideas to get my data into such a new structure without rereading it from the excel files.

Below you find an example of my current "database" where each row below the first one represents the data from one participant.

```
ExperimentCell =

  25×13 cell array

  Columns 1 through 13

    {'Var1'   }    {'Var2'   } ... {'Var13'  }
    {2×30 cell}    {2×30 cell} ... {2×30 cell}
    .
    .
    .
    {2×30 cell}    {2×30 cell} ... {2×30 cell}
```

EDIT As requested, the content of the cells is the following:

`{2x8 cell}` > `{2x8 cell}` > `{2x8 cell}` (where every > denotes a step down in the hierachy).
In each of these levels the first row contains "column headers" (like in the example above with `Var1`) while the row below that contains the "nest link" to the next level. On the last level, each cell in the second row contains a double number (which can be accessed by nested `{}`-indexing)

Comment: Please improve your title to better indicate the task that you are trying to perform. Also, note that appending "matlab:" or whatever library at the beginning is not super helpful as this info is contained in the tags.

Comment: Also show us what the 2x30 cell arrays contain. Are these 2x30 numbers? — also: why not do the analysis in MATLAB? You already have the data there...

Comment: @lmo Updated the title to further reflect on the final goal of the operation
@CrisLuengo Added some further details on the content of the cell objects. Concerning MATLAB analysis: unfortunately not all of the statistical tests I want to perform a available on MATLAB. Therefore, I would like to do the actual data analysis in R. I used MATLAB to read in the data as the `xlsread` function seemed to work better with my for loops.

Comment: Your data structure scares me. Any chance you can re-write the script that reads the data, so it stores it in a more sensical way?

Comment: R matrices and arrays can hold values that are lists. There are also packages that can read matlab object. But you have set up a requirement that we have both Matlab and R, but most of is cannot qualify.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I felt the same way after I ran the script to read the data and noticed that it was stored (let's just say) "unoptimal". Actually I do have the chance. That's why I also asked what would be the optimal way to store the dataset. Should I open up a new question for that?

Comment: @42- I used the R.matlab package and surprisingly it read the nested cell array as an unnamed nested list. But with my data order, it would have been problematic to reorder it.

Comment: @Dom42: It's hard to advise without knowing the relationship between the different elements in your data structure. But what I've seen so far, I'd use something like `experiment(i,j).var1(k,l)`. Note that you can save your data in more than two dimensions also -- sometimes it's useful to store multiple arrays as planes of a higher-dimensional array, so that one index is e.g. the experiment number.

Comment: @CrisLuengo By `experiment(i,j).var1(k,l)` you refer to a struct or table, right? To clarify: My data is coming from one experiment with a within-subject design. Each of the 13 cells (1st level) is a variable, the following 30 (2nd level) are conditions, the following 8 (3rd level) are from trials within this condition and the actual data (4th level, I just noted that I added one more level in the question) is split up into a 1x8 cell array (phases within the trial). I was thinking about an nd-array. Would you say that it might be more appropriate in this case?

Comment: At least for working within MATLAB, a simple nD array is always the simplest and most easy to use option. If R handles such arrays well, I would go with that.

Comment: Just in case, someone stumbles upon this thread and is looking for a solution:
In the end, I was following the `tidy data` approach proposed by [Hadley Wickham](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html). This greatly improved the data handling.